# Find all matrices $A$, so that the map $T$ has the following matrix in standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have to find all matrices $A \in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$, for which the map $T: \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$, $T(X) = A^{-1}XA$ has the following matrix in the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$:

\begin{bmatrix}
-2 & 2 & -4& 4\\
2 & -1 & 1& -2\\
-4 & 4& -4& 4 \\
4& -2& 1& -2
\end{bmatrix}

I tried to write $$A = \begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\
c & d
\end{bmatrix},\qquad A^{-1} = \frac{1}{\det(A)}\begin{bmatrix}
d & -b\\
-c & a
\end{bmatrix},$$
and then solve the system of equations

$$\begin{split}
A^{-1} \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} A &= -2\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} + 2 \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} - 4 \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0\\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix} + 4 \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\\ 
A^{-1} \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}A &= 2\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} -1 \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} + 4 \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0\\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix} -2 \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\\ 
A^{-1} \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0\\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix} A &= -4\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} +  \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} - 4 \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0\\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix} +  \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\\
A^{-1} \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix} A &= 4\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} - 2 \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} + 4 \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0\\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix} -2 \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix},
\end{split}$$
and got that $A = \lambda \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2\\
2 & 2
\end{bmatrix}$, but it was a lot of work. Is there an easier way to find all such matrices $A$, could we maybe use the fact that the map $T$ is a change of basis?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A$ and $B$ be matrices in the set. Then $T(X)=AXA^{-1} = BXB^{-1}$

So $B^{-1}AX = XB^{-1}A$ for all $X$.

But the only matrices that commute with all other matrices are of the form $rI$, so $B^{-1}A = rI$ for some nonzero $r$. So $A$ and $B$ are scalar multiples of each other.

This holds for any $A$ and $B$ in the set, so the set is precisely the set of all matrices of the form $rM$ for $r \ne 0$ for some particular matrix $M$. And any $M$ in the set will work.

This reduces the problem to just finding a matrix which works.